# Why is listable not an attribute of the Set function?

Tags: core-language, attributes

The following is a list of attributes for the `Set` function:

```
Attributes[Set]
```

> ```
> {HoldFirst, Protected, SequenceHold}
> ```

Why is `Listable` not included?

Comment: Would a=Evaluate@Range@5 not make 5 assignments leaving you with a==5?

Comment: That's a good question since `{a,b}={1,2}` sets both `a` and `b` (and not `{a,b}` to `{1,2}` since `{a,b}` is not a symbol.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Listable` is not included because `Set` is not `Listable`, imagine what would happen:

```
foo // Attributes = {Listable};

foo[a, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
```

> ```
> {foo[a, 1], foo[a, 2], foo[a, 3], foo[a, 4], foo[a, 5]}
> ```

That would be unexpected for `Set`. Five assignments instead of one and we end up with `a == 5`.

Why does `{a,b}={1,2}` work then?

Syntactic sugar. Lists are everywhere and many functions are overloaded so that one does not need to use e.g. `Map` or `MapThread` in order to perform common procedure.

You can face it on every corner:

```
StringMatchQ["a"] @ CharacterRange["a", "e"]
```

> ```
> {True, False, False, False, False}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

The key oversight is that the `Listable` attribute does not only allow the upgrading of arguments to equal length lists, as in:

```
SetAttributes[f, Listable]
f[{a, b}, {c, d}] == {f[a, c], f[b, d]}
```

> True

But also that (from the documentation for `Listable`):

> Arguments that are not lists are copied as many times as there are elements in the lists.

So that:

```
f[a, {p, q}] == {f[a, p], f[a, q]}
```

> True

It is this property that allows you to see clearly why `Set` is not listable (thanks to the comment and accepted answer from Kuba).

Say you want to assign a list to a variable, as in:

```
a={1,2,3}
```

The internal form of this is:

```
Set[a,{1,2,3}]
```

If `Set` had the `Listable` attribute, this would interpreted as:

```
{Set[a,1],Set[a,2],Set[a,3]}
```

Resulting only in the assignment `a==3`.